# Modular arithmetic and Fermat's Last Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I have an assignment, and two of the questions are bugging me.

1. Show that in the equation $$x^n + y^n =z^n$$ have a (non-trivial) whole number solution, so  $$x^n + y^n =z^n \pmod p$$ for a prime number $p$, but not the other way around.
2. Show that Fermat's last theorem can be shown by $$x^4 + y^4 =z^4$$ and $$x^p + y^p =z^p $$ where  $p$ is a odd prime.

I really need some help. Thanks.
From a lost senior year highschool student.

Comment: For (1), note that $1^n+1^n\equiv 2^n\pmod{2}$.

Comment: I don't recall exactly how, but if $n$ is the product of two odd primes and neither of those two primes work as an exponent, then that automatically proves that $n$ won't work either.

Comment: (1) "global" implies "local" but not the reciprocal (sorry for language;you can see by yourself  about local an global) (2) $x^4+y^4=z^4$ has been proved by Fermat himself and it is a very known proof; $x^p+y^p=z^p$ by Wiles & Company (very hard and technical)

Comment: Hej @Ataulfo. Thanks for the help. You say that "global" implies "local". I think i know what you mean. But isn't that more a argument then a "show that"? Is just that, im not sure it whould go well in my papir.